# How can I open bootstrap popover always in the center of screen like Modalbox?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have to use popover or tooltip from boostrap... I call popover with classname from a lot of button.. I just want to open all button popover in the center of screen with javascript.

THX

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap modal instead? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Comment: this is modalbox,, I need popover

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your attempt and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I think it is very simple question to understand... if you didnt understand that means that : You dont know answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a css-class for all popover so u can identify them and loop over all elements and show them.

Here some example code:

```js
// Get all elements with 'my-popover-class' class
const popoverCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('my-popover-class');
// Add your options
const popoverOptions = {};

for(let i = 0; i < popoverCollection .length; i++) {
   let popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverCollection[i], popoverOptions );
   popover.show();
}
```